# google forms api quickstart python

Tags: python, google-forms, google-forms-api

I want to run this code https://developers.google.com/forms/api/quickstart/python that makes requests to google forms.
My question is how to get the credentials generate  `token.json` file

```
from __future__ import print_function

from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import client, file, tools

SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body"
DISCOVERY_DOC = "https://forms.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"

store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = None
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

form_service = discovery.build('forms', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(
    Http()), discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_DOC, static_discovery=False)
```

Comment: there is one mistake - it should be `creds = store.get()` instead of `creds = None`

Comment: as I remeber at first start it should redirect you to Google page, it should ask you for permissions to access your data and it should send back `token` which it should save automatically in file `token.json` but all this should be in example code on Google.

Comment: [examples for other APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) have line with `with open('token.json', 'w') as token: token.write(creds.to_json())` which is excuted when you accept permissions

Answer (score 0):

The part most relevant to your question is here:

```py
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = None
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

Trying to put it simply:

- The `store` variable defines a local file where the token will be located, in this case it's `token.json`.
- Then the `flow` object tries to look for a file called `client_secrets.json` where your credentials should be located. There's an explanation on how to generate these credentials from the Cloud Console [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingcred). Once you have this file you can just place it in the same folder as your `quickstart.py`. Make sure that the name in the method matches the name in the directory.
- Then [`tools.run_flow(flow, store)`](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.tools.html) will use the credentials in the `flow` object (which are in your `client_secrets.json` file) to run a temporary webserver and open a page in your browser where you have to go through the OAuth flow to authorize the app. Once this flow is done, the resulting token will be written to the `token.json` file which you defined in the `store` variable. The `creds` variable can then be used to run API calls.

For some reason the Forms quickstart you linked has a few differences from others as pointed out by [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73304064/google-forms-api-quickstart-python#comment129461278_73304064). The difference in the [Drive API sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) is that it checks for the `token.json` file first so if it exists it won't go through the OAuth flow. On the other hand the Forms quickstart seems like it would go through the flow every time without checking, and it also uses a different method to run the flow. This is the part in the authorization that changes:

```py
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

I don't know if there's a technical reason for this discrepancy in the documentation or if it's just an oversight/outdated way to do it, but you can just replace the top code block with the one at the bottom and it should work either way, but the second is preferable. Just keep in mind that you will need the `credentials.json` file in the same location as the script file.

##### Sources:

- [Create authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingcred)
- [oauth2client.tools module](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.tools.html)
- [Flow module](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html)